# Python search file and print line if matches anything in array

Tags: python, arrays, file

I have an array with multiple strings in it. I need to search through a file to see if any line in the file matches with any of the strings in the array and print all the lines from the file that matches

this is what i have so far, but my python syntax/logic is a little off

```
under30=[] is the array of multiple strings i want to match against the file 
with open("list.txt") as f2:
        for line in f2:
                if under30() in line:
                        print line
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `under30` is your list of string to match from the file

`if under30() in line:`

should be:

`if line in under30:`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
file_data = [i.strip('\n') for i in open('filename.txt')]
under30=["string1", "string2", "string3"]
final_lines = [i for i in file_data if i in under30]
```